# LINQ to SQL and dynamic query on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, windows-phone

Is there a way to execute a pure T-SQL Query against the SQL Compact Database on Windows phone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to do this, as can be seen in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202872%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

It states;

> ExecuteCommand is not supported: Windows Phone does not support executing “raw” Transact-SQL, Data Definition Language (DDL), or Data Modeling Language (DML) statements.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to execute T-SQL on Windows Phone platform.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860(v=vs.105).aspx